# Family over a set such that the union is the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, multisets

I'm new to combinatorics, so this may be a common scenario with which I'm unfamiliar.

I'm trying to define a family of set $\mathbb{F}$ over a set $\mathcal{S}$, where the size of each member of $\mathbb{F}$ is *not* fixed and the empty set is excluded, such that the union of all members of $\mathbb{F}$ is equal to $\mathcal{S}$ itself.

First question is - what is the standard set notation for that? My guess is along the lines of

$$
\mathbb{F} := \left\{f \in \mathfrak{p}(\mathcal{S}) \mid \bigcup f = \mathcal{S} \right\}
$$

Second question - what if $\mathcal{S}$ is a multiset? In my particular case, it would be the sum of the multiplicities from each member of $\mathbb{F}$ rather than the maximum of the multiplicities.

Lastly - where can I find out more about these types of cases? I expect this is a common application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{ f $\subseteq$ P(S) - {empty set} : $\cup$f = S }
is what you want.

Comment: So, I wasn't too far off. Does the same notation work for multisets, or does the $\cup$ change to a $\uplus$?

Comment: That is the largest family of such sets.  Obviously, the singleton set {S} is another.  Or given that a is a member of S, {S- {a}, {a}} is another family whose union is S.

Comment: @user247327, It's for generalizing a specific application, so I want to define the entities. I have $n$ samples drawn from some unknown set, of which $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of all the samples, so the family of sets over $\mathcal{S}$ are the $n$ samples that would naturally be members of the power set of $\mathcal{S}$. Each sample contains some variable proportion of $\mathcal{S}$ due to the underlying processes. I'm just trying to formalize it all into an appropriate combinatorial format.